# How to add 'checked' to a select item in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have two nested `map` in a `select`, in the bottom I add the `option` elements.

```js
return (
    <Modal completion={completion}>
        <InputGroup title="Program" numOfAsterisks={1}>
            <Select formState={formState} setFormState={setFormState} name={'type'}>
                <option value="">- Válassz -</option>
                {Object.entries(programEventTimes ?? {})
                    .sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
                    .map(([key, value]) => (
                        <>
                            {Object.entries(value ?? {})
                                .sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
                                .map(([key2, value2]) => (
                                    <option value="textField" {key == ticket.eventName && key2 == ticket.startTime && 'checked' }>
                                        {key} - {key2}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                        </>
                    ))}
            </Select>
        </InputGroup>
    </Modal>
```

Somehow at `{key` part it says:

> '...' expected.

Why whould I use `...`?

Comment: [`option` should be `selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected) not `checked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be `selected` and not `checked`
Then you condition to have `selected` as props must be

```js
<option value="textField" selected={key == ticket.eventName && key2 == ticket.startTime}>
```

Please also note that `==` is not recommended, and prefer using `===` to avoid type mistakes

Answer (score 0):

It mean if you want to pass object prop to child you need to use `...` syntax like this

```html
<option value="textField" {...{selected: key == ticket.eventName && key2 == ticket.startTime}}>
     {key} - {key2}
</option>
```

`...` is spread operator .In react `...` will help spread your object`obj={key:value}` `<span {...obj} />` into this  `<span key={value}/>`